# For $a>0$, what is $\int_1^\infty dy \, \exp(-ay) (y^2-1)^{-1/2}y^{-2}$?

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, bessel-functions

As the title states.

I've determined that for $a>0$ and $m\in\mathbb N$,

$$\int_1^\infty dy \,e^{-ay}\frac{y^m}{\sqrt{y^2-1}} = (-1)^mK^{(m)}_0(a),$$

where $K^{(m)}_0(a)$ is the $m^\mathrm{th}$ derivative of the usual modified Bessel function of zeroth order evaluate at $a$.

By integrating under the integral sign, I find that for $a>0$ $$\int_1^\infty dy \,e^{-ay}\frac{y^{-1}}{\sqrt{y^2-1}} = \int_a^\infty da'K_0(a') = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi a}{2}\big( K_0(a)L_{-1}(a) + K_1(a)L_0(a) \big),$$ where $L_n(z)$ is the modified Struve function.

If I integrate under the integral sign again I'm stuck with an expression for which I'm unaware of a closed form solution, $$\int_1^\infty dy \,e^{-ay}\frac{y^{-2}}{\sqrt{y^2-1}} = \int_a^\infty da' \Big[\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi a'}{2}\big( K_0(a')L_{-1}(a') + K_1(a')L_0(a') \big)\Big].$$

Does anyone know of a closed form solution to the title integral, the above integral, or an equivalent?  Thank you very much!

EDIT: following from Paul's answer below, one can find a somewhat nice closed form solution for the result of integration, $\operatorname{Ki}_2(z)$.  Using Eq. 10.43.17 from Olver, https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43#E17, with $\operatorname{Ki}_0(z)=K_0(z)$ and $\operatorname{Ki}_1(z) = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi a}{2}\big( K_0(a)L_{-1}(a) + K_1(a)L_0(a) \big)$ one has that $$\int_1^\infty dy \,e^{-ay}\frac{y^{-2}}{\sqrt{y^2-1}} = \operatorname{Ki}_2(a) = a K_1(a) + \frac\pi2a\big( aK_0(a)L_{-1}(a)+aK_1(a)L_0(a)-1 \big).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed integral is a [Bickley-Naylor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bickley%E2%80%93Naylor_functions). It can be defined as
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname {Ki} _{n}(x)=\int _{1}^{\infty }{\frac {e^{-xt}\,dt}{t^{n}{\sqrt {t^2-1}}}}
\end{equation}
For $n=2$, which is the case of interest,
\begin{align}
 \operatorname {Ki} _{2}(x)=1-{\frac {\pi }{2}}x-&{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}\left(\gamma +\ln \left({\frac {x}{2}}\right)\right)\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(x^{2}/4)^{k}}{k!(k+1)!(2k+1)}}+\\
 &+{\frac {x^{2}}{4}}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(4k+3)(x^{2}/4)^{k}}{k!(k+1)!(2k+1)^{2}}}+{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(x^{2}/4)^{k}\Phi (k+1)}{k!(k+1)!(2k+1)}}
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant and $\phi(k+1)=1+1/2+1/3+\cdots+1/k$.

and for $x\to\infty$, $\operatorname {Ki} _{2}(x)\simeq e^{-x}(\pi/\sqrt{2x})$.

The Wikipedia link provides several properties and references.

Comment: This was _perfect_. Thank you very much!! You saved me much, much agony. For future readers, using Bickley-Naylor as a search term, I found https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98910/37925, which gives the Bickley-Naylor function in terms of the Meijer G function, which allows for easy numerical evaluation in, say, Mathematica.